# Как динамически передать ИМЯ аргумента в функцию?

Tags: python-3.x

Понятное дело что так как я делаю - нельзя. Но хотелось бы что то в этом духе...

```
def func1(arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print(f"arg2: {arg2}, arg3: {arg3}")

def func2(arg1):
    obj = func1(f"{arg1}"=123)

test = func2("arg2")
```

Предположим что доступа к func1 у меня нет (или я ну очень не хочу ее трогать). И мне необходимо динамически подставлять ИМЕНА аргументов (со значениями понятно всё) в эту функцию. Тоесть то что обычно делается со значениями, я хотел бы еще делать и с именами. Может для этого есть правильное форматирование?

Comment: как вариант можно использовать распаковку словаря: `func1(**{"arg1": 123, "arg2": 345})`, а словарь создавать динамически - не проблема

Comment: Используйте аргумент `**kwargs`, тогда аргументы вида `arg1=123` и `arg2=456` будут в `kwargs` как словарь: `{"arg1": 123, "arg2": 456}`

Comment: угу, разобрался. спасибо.